# Dealing with categorical variables in Isolation Forest

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, unsupervised-learning, categorical-data, isolation-forest

Isolation Forest is widely used when dealing with outlier/anomaly detection when we have no labels. The theory behind is that making random split at random points and counting how many splits you do to isolate a feature will help you determine if an instance is or not an outlier.

I have categorical features and I am not sure how to deal with them:

- Label Encoding: Will misrepresent the data in euclidean space.
- One Hot Encoding: Will give me more features and since the source code first selects the columns and then the values, it will give a non-realistic probability for my algorithm to select the one hot encoded
- Target Encoding wont work since we have no target

**How to properly encode categorical features in Isolation Forest?**
Could we encode categorical features  in a space that suits the algorithm

Comment: How about other unsupervised ways of encoding e.g. Binary, Count, Hashing etc. (avaiable at https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders)? I think Catboost uses some of these methods to encode categorical variables automatically, well that is an gradient boosting trees, but I am mentioning so that you can use them too in Isolation Forest.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of categoy encoders. My question is what is the best and why? Catboost Encoded is target encoding but with some fancy functionalities, but at the end target encoding, so it requires a label

Comment: Catboost has more than just target encoding but that is beyond the point. Then your Q is not clear. What is the best way to encode either supervised or unsupervised is general question in many algorithms. Better to redefine the question 'How to properly encode categorical features in Isolation Forest?' by adding at the end 'in order to..'. What is the criteria here? Those cons you listed are generic issues with such encoding methods and not limited to IF.

Comment: I understand that IF is an algorithm for outlier/anomaly detection. Thanks for the edit suggestion

Comment: @TwinPenguins in the catboost encoding it says "This is very similar to leave-one-out encoding," and in the leave one out documentation "This is very similar to target encoding "

Comment: @TwinPenguins https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.13783

Comment: Your own paper/method, bravo! Will have a look. Is it already included in sktools?

Comment: It is included in sktools, also in category_encoders. Even thought category_encoders needs to do a package release to be able to use it.